# ServiceStack: replace a web service with a message queue

Tags: .net, rest, servicestack, message-queue

I'm working on a project that provides some API for getting information about our partners' products.

Every search request to our site has to make n other requests to partners sites, collect and aggregate products data so it could take much time.

At the moment we're experiencing some performance issues because of the blocking REST service and I'm looking for a better solution to organize our product search platform.

As I've seen the ServiceStack RedisMQ can provide an asynchronous solution for long time communications. But I've got some questions (because I've got not much experience with MQ):

1. How could I substitute a REST service with an MQ
2. How could I get information from an MQ on a web page (with REST I can use any suitable JS lib like jQuery and make ajax requests)
3. How could I organize an MQ API for my service instead of REST that can be used by our customers (on their sites).

Comment: Have you tried TPL. For ex, `Parallel.Invoke(()=>SearchSite1(),()=>SearchSite2());`

Comment: yep. but these requests can really take a long time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what language you are using, so I'll try to be language agnostic.

I would suggest that you should make your app "stream" data back rather than wait on the blocking restful call to return. All the partner "fetches" must be executed as async callback, 
As results arrive, you can write back to the stream.

IMHO, switching to a message queue won't really buy you anything. At the most elementary form, view message queues as communication channels in a distributed computing environment. The transport mechanisms can vary - but primarily a Queue is point to point communication mechanism.